# How to find out what is blocking ssh traffic

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, firewall, manjaro

I paid for a VPS, and it has a ssh connection option. Giving its IP address and provided port (22), i'm trying to connect:

```
ssh -vvvv user@ip
```

and get the connection timeout with such output:

```
OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.1.3 19 Sep 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 49: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <ip> is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to <ip> [<ip>] port 22.
```

I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415021/cannot-ssh-to-server-linux-machine/1418608#1418608) with a flag:

```
ssh -o IPQoS=none -vvvv user@ip
```

but it doesn't help, the output is the same. SSH config file is default.

I tried to **PING** this ip, and the packets are transmitted. But neither **netcat**, nor **telnet** can't establish a connection with this ip by 22 port. Also, **nmap** says that traffic is filtered out:

```
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-26 01:47 MSK
Nmap scan report for <ip>
Host is up (0.049s latency).

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.56 seconds
```

As nmap doc says: *The filtering could be from a dedicated firewall device, router rules, or host-based firewall software*. But my firewall is turned off:

```
sudo ufw status                                                                                                                                                                                  
Status: inactive
```

And **iptables** out is the next:

```
sudo iptables --list                                                                                                                                                                             
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

So, nothing illegal!
My PC is working on WiFi (via adapter on b650 motherboard). I also have a MacOS notebook at home, which is working on the same network, and it doesn't have any problems connecting to this address via ssh (no vpn needed, nothing else). That means, the problem is local for my pc. VPS support said that there are no restrictions on their side, and that my problem is local. Btw, **traceroute** from my problem pc and from mac laptop are absolutely identical!

I also tried to sniff a traffic with wireshark, found some packets sent to this IP (they were TCP Retransmitted many times unsuccesffully), but i barely understood what is going on there.

So, my main question is how can I figure out what blocks my ssh traffic to this ip, and how can i unfilter it.

My OS:

```
Linux MyUser 6.1.55-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Sep 23 12:13:56 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPD**: problem not solved, but workarounded by changing sshd port on VPS server - it helped me, and my pc now can establish a connection with a new port. But if i rollback sshd port to default 22 - it breaks again (still i can only connect to it only from laptop). I guess, the problem may be on my router (may be NAT or smth else, which makes incoming packets from this ip:port redirected to other host of LAN, or just drops it, idk). So, problem is not actual for me, but if someone can describe possible reasons of such behavior (for our descendants) - it will be cool =)

Comment: Install `tracepath` - TCP traceroute. It will let you specify a port number. Read `man tracepath`.

Comment: Does your VPS run an SSH server? Have you confirmed it is running, through KVM console for example? "But my firewall is turned off" - which one? The one on your client (which does not matter), or the one on your VPS?

Comment: If you are sure that `sshd` is running and there is no configuration on your VPS that should block it, open a ticket with your hosting provider.

Comment: @Panki of course yes, ssh is working on the remote vps server (as I wroute, i successfully connect to it from my laptop, which works on the same wifi network).

"But my firewall is turned off - which one?" - to be honest, i don't understand much about firewalls. I provided ufw and iptables output in original post. And this is my main question - what else can block my ssh traffic?

Comment: @Panki, Thank you for your answer! "If you are sure that sshd is running and there is no configuration on your VPS that should block it, open a ticket with your hosting provider" - yes, as i already said twice, sshd is running and available. Its not available only from my concrete local pc. And I already created a ticket, support answered that this is my local problem and they don't have any restrictive policies configured

Comment: @waltinator thank you for answering me, but tracepath not available on manjaro, instead it has traceroute. Anyhow, I don't fully understand how should i use it.

Comment: Regarding firewall: the question is on which system you ran `iptables -L` etc., your local one or the remote VPS? So, let me get this straight - your laptop on wifi can use SSH, but your desktop on LAN (same home network) can't?

Comment: @Panki absolutely yes!
"etc., your local one or the remote VPS?" - i ran it on local PC

Comment: UPD: problem not solved, but workarounded by changing sshd port on VPS server - it helped me, and my pc now can establish a connection with a new port. But if i rollback sshd port to default 22 - it breaks again (still i can only connect to it only from laptop).
I guess, the problem may be on my router (may be NAT or smth else, which makes incoming packets from this ip:port redirected to other host of LAN, or just drops it, idk). So, problem is not actual for me, but if someone can describe possible reasons of such behavior (for our descendants) - it will be cool =)